# TableView is not displayed how it's supposed to

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a table view in Xcode and when I run the project it's displayed awfully (pic related).
Don't know what could be the problem.
What I did was:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let fruit = ["Apple", "Prune", "Grapes", "Watermelon", "Melon", "Cherry"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruit.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! FruitTableViewCell

        cell.fruitLable.text = fruit[indexPath.row]
        cell.fruitImage.image = UIImage(named: fruit[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}

import UIKit

class FruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitLable: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: no attached pics

Comment: Please attach the pic

Comment: BTW - don't take an actual photograph of your computer screen. The simulator makes it easy to take a screenshot. File | New Screen Shot.

Comment: You need add delegate func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `heightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
```

Comment: I did it, the whole thing looks better but still can't see the images near the texts.

Comment: You can either increase height or google how to use automatic table cells

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Anyway, those who voted me down, are the last egoists on earth.
Why don't you think about those to who you do it ?
They wind up being blocked from asking questions only because of their egoism.